# Facebook Pixel, Standard Events Code and Google Tag Manager

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I have installed Facebook's Pixel Base Code, sitewide on a website, using Google Tag Manager (I assume that this is okay to do now that Facebook is providing instructions on how to use GTM).

My question here is, in order to insert the "Standard Events Code" on the page I want to measure (e.g. a LEAD) - can I simply use Google Tag Manager to insert this code (as a separate tag) on the page I want?

Comment: I have discovered that is possible to insert both of these codes, using Google Tag Manager. I set the Pixel Base Code to "1" so that it loads first.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can install the Facebook standard event codes with Google tag manager. The important thing to keep in mind is to fire the Facebook base pixel first and then the event pixel. With tag manager it is more easier to pass parameters and send product details for dynamic remarketing. here is a detailed guide for Facebook standard event tracking in google tag manager http://marketlytics.com/blog/facebook-conversion-tracking-google-tag-manager

regards

Analytics ML